# SQL - Group based on multi - columns

Tags: sql-server

I have table like the following :

```
A_ID         Area_Code        Status
1               AAA             2         
2               BBB             1         
3               AAA             2         
4               AAA             3         
5               AAA             2         
6               BBB             2         
7               BBB             1         
8               AAA             4         
9               AAA             5         
10              AAA             4
```

And i want the result set like :

**A_Code**   **Count_A_Code**     **Count_Sts1**        **Count_Sts2**     **Count_Sts3**   **Count_Sts4**       **Count_Sts5**

```
AAA         7            0         3          1        2          1

BBB         3            2         1          0        0          0
```

Please note that i have only 5 statues . so i need the statues to be columns ..

I appreciate any help . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select area_code as a_code,
       count(*) as count_a_code,
       sum(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as code_count_sts1,
       sum(case when status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as code_count_sts2,
       sum(case when status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as code_count_sts3,
       sum(case when status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as code_count_sts4,
       sum(case when status = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as code_count_sts5
from your_table
group by area_code
```